# MVC 4 Views, common or specific?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my first time using MVC, first time writing a web application as well.

So far, I managed to have a view for a list of employees, and an edit view for the Employee model.

If I had 25 models that I need displayed as lists, and edited, will I have to create 50 different views?

or is there a way to have one common List View and one common Edit View?

(edit below)

Solved the List View issue.
Sorry for the long code.

I created a **ModelPropertyInfo** class that describes model properties. For now I only added the Label, but I might add more properties like "Format", "InputType", ...

```
// Model field information class. Used by views to display model info properly
public class ModelPropertyInfo
{
    public ModelPropertyInfo() { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

}
```

Then the **ShowInListAttribute** attribute class to decorate only model properties that I want to appear in the list view

```
// Attribute class used to specify Labels for model fields
public class ShowInListAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ShowInListAttribute(string header)
    {
        Header = header;
    }

    public string Header { get; set; }
}
```

And a **ModelBase** class that all my models will inherit. This class will give the ability to get any property value from the class by passing its name as **string**

```
// Base class for all models
public class ModelBase
{
    public static List<ModelPropertyInfo> ModelProperties(Type modelType)
    {
        List<ModelPropertyInfo> result = new List<ModelPropertyInfo>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in modelType.GetProperties())
        {
            ShowInListAttribute att = (ShowInListAttribute)pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ShowInListAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
            if (att != null)
                result.Add(new ModelPropertyInfo { Label = att.Header, Name = pi.Name });
        }
        return result;
    }

    public object GetPropertyValue(string propName)
    {
        return this.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(this, null);
    }
}
```

Now, here's my **Employee** model class

```
[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee : ModelBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public decimal ID { get; set; }

    [ShowInList("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [ShowInList("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public decimal DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [ShowInList("Department")]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

So, to put all the above to use, here's the Index method in my **EmployeeController**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Columns = ModelBase.ModelProperties(typeof(Employee));
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee List";
    return View("ListShared", db.Employees.ToList());
}
```

Finally, the result, the SharedListView that I will use to display a list of any model I want

```
@using SharedListView.Models 

@model IEnumerable<ModelBase>



<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach (ModelPropertyInfo col in ViewBag.Columns)
        {
            <th>
                @col.Label
            </th>
        }
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            @foreach (ModelPropertyInfo col in ViewBag.Columns)
            {
                <td width='100px'>
                    @item.GetPropertyValue(col.Name).ToString()
                </td>
            }
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.GetPropertyValue("ID") }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.GetPropertyValue("ID") }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.GetPropertyValue("ID") })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Still stuck on a common Edit view, any help would be appreciated.

Again, sorry for the long edit.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do that. The ASP.NET MVC supports ContentFor method and EditorFor method. So in your case, you only need to designing your view models, and afterwards on your view, you can use its like

```
@Html.ContentFor(Model.Employee) // for display - that mean, it should be read-only
@Html.EditorFor(Model.Employee) // for editing.
```

You can see the post about that topic [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx)

Comment: ContentFor(Model.Employee)?

Comment: The Model is of type Employee, so I think you meant something like @Html.ContentFor(Employee.Name). And I can't fine the ContentFor Html helper anywhere.

Comment: Sorry guys. I mean @Html.ContentFor(Model)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have this structure for each model object:

1. ListView: Display the list of item. And create a viewmodel class for each item in the view
2. CreateView: Used when creating new object. Also having ViewModel class for this
3. EditView: the same as CreateView, except it is for edit mode

This structure will create many views with ViewModel that look similar. However, they are not since in the nature they are different for different purposes. The structure will improve the code in term of separation of concern, help in maintenance. Easy to work with.

Comment: I managed to create a List view that can display any model object of any type. check my edit. Still have to figure out the Edit and Create views. much harder I guess.

Comment: I know what you mean and i have done something similar before with ASP.NET. However it caused my headache when the object type grows and especially when we need custom rule/action which will offer for each type. That was why i suggest you that way

Answer (score 0):

checkout [Knockout.js](http://www.knockoutjs.com).  I have written applications like what you are talking about, a view for a collection of data and a view for editing the individual records.  knockout makes it fairly easy to integrate the editing portion of the views into the collection viewing.  It does help to have some understanding of WPF and Silverlight style data bindings.  All of my views now use knockout and I integrate the editing functionality in the collection views with proper data binding using the visible binding to a editor area.

Answer (score 0):

Your view will use a model to display or edit the data. If you have 25 different models, every view should have a different model.
If you want to use just one model, mainly because they share similar properties, this can be done but it is not ideal. The way it can be done is if all the models have similar properties, you can include all the properties in one model. Then you can just use the properties you need in other views. This is not the ideal way of doing it. Every view should have its own model.

Answer (score 0):

You could create some sort of class that generates the html for all the different types of "form inputs" you will need in your app. Then add ability to the class to receive data from the models (ie. takes a string from the model and creates a TEXT input with the value set to that string .... or a SELECT dropdown can receive all it's OPTIONs from a model, etc).

Then all these form inputs can be generated from within the models (utilizing your class) and can be pumped into an array that is passed to your single view. The view would contain all the surrounding divs and other html, but somewhere in the view you would put a small "for loop" that outputs your array's contents. This is valid MVC, in that you are only using a simple for-loop in your view. And your models, to some extent may be partially responsible in deciding how the data if formatted coming out of the database (in this case, form inputs). To style the form inputs, you can keep the styling in a css file or at the top of the view.

Ultimately it depends on the future of your app. This is an idea if your app and models fit in a nice repetitive structure. But if you suspect parts of your app might evolve, where sometimes you might need a view to look much differently, or you want more control over how you arrange each of those generated "form inputs" in the views, then you will probably be creating a higher number of views.